# How to use GADInterstitialAd in GoogleMobileAds 8.0 (Admob iOS sdk)?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

On February 2, Google updated the library for displaying ads on iOS to version 8.0. At the same time, there are no examples of how to use the new api in the official documentation. I am using full screen banner, how to display it in new sdk version?

Comment: Same for me. Still not working. Version 8.7.0

Answer (score 0):

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController, GADFullScreenContentDelegate {
    
    var ad: GADInterstitialAd!
  
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadAd()
    }
  
    func loadAd() {
       let id = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910"
       GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID: id, request: GADRequest()) { ad, error in
            if error != nil { return }
            self.ad = ad
            self.ad.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
            self.ad.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        }
    }
  
    func adDidPresentFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        print("present-ads")
    }
    
    func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        print("dismiss-ads")
    }
  
}
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  
  func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
    {
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start()
        return true
    }
  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Starting from the excellent example of nullproduction, I suggest presenting the ad with a separate function. Call presentAdWhenYouWant() to present Ad

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController, GADFullScreenContentDelegate {

    var ad: GADInterstitialAd!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       loadAd()
    }

    func loadAd() {
       let id = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910"
       GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID: id, request: GADRequest()) { (ad, error) in
           if error != nil { return }
              self.ad = ad
              self.ad.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
           }
      }

     func adDidPresentFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
         print("present-ads")
     }

     func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        print("dismiss-ads")
     }

 
     func presentAdWhenYouWant {
          do {
             if try self.gADInterstitialAd.canPresent(fromRootViewController: self.parents) {
                self.gADInterstitialAd?.present(fromRootViewController: self.parents!)
            }
        } catch {
        
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: What is self.parents?

Comment: `canPresent` also shows error `Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected condition type 'Bool'`